# Bootstrap Inline form in a <li> element

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to align a simple form inside of a `li` element:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>list item text</span>
        <form class="inline-form">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
            </button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.4. The form renders below the text, and I want it to render beside it. [The same code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvz6wuex/2/). I suppose this is trivial, but I know how to do some stuff on the backend, and when it comes to frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your CSS file to see the result you want:

```
.inline-form {
    display: inline;
}
```